# Ruby On Rails. Destroy Method does not work if link has been voted on *Reddit Clone*

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am able to delete the links that are assigned to each user, unless they are voted upon. If a link has any votes on it the delete method being called no longer works.

Here is a link to the website deployed on heroku. If you sign up. submit a link, vote it up or down and then try to delete you will see the error I am experiencing.

https://salty-eyrie-2549.herokuapp.com/

EDIT: After launching the app live i found the code works as long as the app is not being hosted locally... Very Strange...

This is the error I am getting.

NoMethodError in LinksController#destroy

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #59):

```
# DELETE /links/1.json
def destroy
    @link.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to links_url, notice: 'Link was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
```

Rails.root: /Users/ipbyrne/FirstRailsApp/raddit

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/links_controller.rb:59:in `destroy'
Request

Parameters:

```
{"_method"=>"delete",
 "authenticity_token"=>"3JyyNGNPHhdVcQ7tZQ64t+ouQjiNFnwxQXw25fgJGX4=",
 "id"=>"5"}
```

I am using the act_as_votable ruby gem.

The first block below is my show.html.erb where the destroy method is being called from

The second block is my links_controller.rb file.

```js
<div class="page-header">
    <h1><a href="<%= @link.url %>"><%= @link.title %></a><br> <small>Submitted by <%= @link.user.name %></small></h1>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
 <%= link_to 'Visit URL', @link.url, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>

<div class="btn-group pull-right">
  <%= link_to like_link_path(@link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
    Upvote
    <%= @link.get_upvotes.size %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to dislike_link_path(@link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">
    Downvote
    <%= @link.get_downvotes.size %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<% if @link.user == current_user -%>
 <div class="btn-group">
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_link_path(@link), class: "btn btn-default" %>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy', @link, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-default" %>
 </div>
<% end %>

<h3 class="comments_title">
  <%= @link.comments.count %> Comments
</h3>

<div id="comments">
  <%= render :partial => @link.comments %>
</div>
<%= simple_form_for [@link, Comment.new]  do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <%= f.submit "Add Comment", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

```html
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_link, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :authorized_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /links
  # GET /links.json
  def index
    @links = Link.all
  end

  # GET /links/1
  # GET /links/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /links/new
  def new
    @link = current_user.links.build
  end

  # GET /links/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /links
  # POST /links.json
  def create
    @link = current_user.links.build(link_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.save
        format.html { redirect_to @link, notice: 'Link was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @link }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @link.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /links/1
  # PATCH/PUT /links/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.update(link_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @link, notice: 'Link was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @link }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @link.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /links/1
  # DELETE /links/1.json
  def destroy
    @link.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to links_url, notice: 'Link was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def upvote
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    @link.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def downvote
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    @link.downvote_from current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_link
      @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    end

    def authorized_user
      @link = current_user.links.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to links_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this link" if @link.nil?
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def link_params
      params.require(:link).permit(:title, :url)
    end
end
```

Full Trace Error

```
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:80:in `cached_counter_attribute_name'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:103:in `inverse_updates_counter_cache?'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:113:in `delete_records'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:493:in `remove_records'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:486:in `block in delete_or_destroy'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:152:in `block in transaction'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:200:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:151:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:486:in `delete_or_destroy'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:247:in `destroy'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:170:in `destroy_all'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:26:in `handle_dependency'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:97:in `has_many_dependent_for_votes_for'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:377:in `_run__4103742494544083763__destroy__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:289:in `destroy'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:265:in `block in destroy'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transaction'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transaction'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:265:in `destroy'
app/controllers/links_controller.rb:59:in `destroy'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:443:in `_run__1823692881447443679__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1414070385979111640__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/ipbyrne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/ipbyrne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/ipbyrne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Link.rb

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
     acts_as_votable
     belongs_to :user
     has_many :comments
end
```

Schema

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150722133429) do

  create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "link_id"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "comments", ["link_id"], name: "index_comments_on_link_id"
  add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"

  create_table "links", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "url"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "links", ["user_id"], name: "index_links_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

  create_table "votes", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "votable_id"
    t.string   "votable_type"
    t.integer  "voter_id"
    t.string   "voter_type"
    t.boolean  "vote_flag"
    t.string   "vote_scope"
    t.integer  "vote_weight"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "votes", ["votable_id", "votable_type", "vote_scope"], name: "index_votes_on_votable_id_and_votable_type_and_vote_scope"
  add_index "votes", ["voter_id", "voter_type", "vote_scope"], name: "index_votes_on_voter_id_and_voter_type_and_vote_scope"

end
```

Link Model

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base


    acts_as_votable
     belongs_to :user
     has_many :comments 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're unable to delete it because the link has associated votes. You will have to update the relationships in your `Link` model so that it allows `allow_destroy: true`, in which case it will delete the associations as well.

Comment: I believe that is exactly whats going on. so i just need to add allow_destroy: true into the link model? I added the link model to give you an idea of what it looks like.

Comment: `has_many :comments , dependent: :destroy` is what you need. It'll delete all comments associated with the link when deleting the link.

Comment: The problem is not the post with comments on them cant be deleted, the problem is the post with upvotes or down votes on them cant be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The error must be in your `index.html.erb` file. You are calling 'name' on some nil object.

Comment: Just added the full trace to the original question.

Comment: First full trace was of wrong error. Just fixed and put up original error

Comment: @Isaac Kindly add link.rb and schema of link.

Comment: just added them both. and thank you for helping me resolve this.